# How to fork the youngest process

Tags: c, unix, signals, fork

Let's say that whenever main program receives SIGINT signal, the youngest (i.e. the lastly forked) process is forked. In other words:

```
p1 SIGINT

p1->p2 SIGINT

p1->p2->p3
```

and so on

My problem is that I don't know how to tell the grand-grand-...-children to fork.

Comment: Unclear. Read [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and  [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The main process `p1` receives `SIGNT` and then it forks and `p2` process is created. Next, `p1` receives `SIGNT` again and `p2` forks and creates `p3`. And so on

Comment: The logic here is simple:  on receiving `SIGINT`, send `SIGINT` to the child process.  If there is no child process yet, call `fork()`.

Comment: You may be able to use process groups. The parent creates its own process group. When it receives the first SIGINT, it creates a child. Thereafter, when it receives a SIGINT, it sends the signal to the process group. The processes in the process group handle the interrupt; if they've not forked yet, they do so now, and thereafter can ignore interrupts (since they won't fork a second time). There are likely some gotchas in this — but I'm not yet sure what they are. And simply rippling the interrupt down the chain of processes is probably simpler. I think children could exit with process groups.

Comment: Don't all the children get the SIGINT signal too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that I don't know how to tell the
>   grand-grand-...-children to fork.

1. Parent should install SIGINT handler using SA_SIGINFO flag.
2. When a grandchild is created it should send signal to parent(p1).
3. P1 through its signal handler(si_pid field of handler's siginfo_t argument) reads pid of grandchild.
4. When Parent receives SIGINT then it send signal to grand child.
5. When grand child receives signal it should fork a new child.
6. Repeat from 2-5 for newly created child.

One more approach:

1. Let parent poll for SIGINT signal.
2. When SIGINT received by parent, create child.
3. Mask SIGINT in parents context and wait for SIGINT in child context.
4. repeat step 1 to 3 in childs context.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define CHILD_NEEDED 10
static volatile sig_atomic_t got_sigint;
static volatile sig_atomic_t child_created;

void sigint_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *f, void *main_context) {

        ucontext_t *uc = main_context;

        // to mask SIGINT while returning from handler.
        sigaddset(&uc->uc_sigmask, SIGINT);

       ++child_created;
        got_sigint = 1;
}

void create_child(void)
{

        pid_t pid = fork();
        sigset_t set;
        sigemptyset(&set);

        if (-1 == pid) {
                perror("Fork failed\n");
                exit(1);
        } else if (0 == pid) {
              // Exit if expected child are created
               if (child_created == CHILD_NEEDED) {
                    printf("New Child\nTotal Child: %d\n", child_created);
                    exit(0);
            }
                got_sigint = 0;
                // As parent mask is copied to child so clear child mask set.
                sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &set, NULL);
                printf("New Child\n Please send signal to create child\n");
                while (!got_sigint);
                create_child();
        }

}
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

        struct sigaction act = {.sa_sigaction = sigint_handler, .sa_mask = 0, .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO};
        sigset_t mask;
        int status;


        parent = getpid();

        sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);
        printf("parent\n Please send signal to create child\n");

        while (!got_sigint);
        // As we have returned from signal so SIGINT will be mask for parent.
        create_child();

       // parent will wait here.
        wait(&status);
        exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All your processes will receive the SIGINT signal, so the main process doesn't need to tell the youngest process to fork; just let the process that hasn't forked yet fork, and all other processes do nothing.